# PHP JSON Format Currency Comma

Tags: php, json, steam, currency-formatting

I'm new to PHP.

My code reads a price value from a Steam game's json data.

```
http://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails/?appids=8870
```

Problem is that the value of the price node is not formatted with a comma separator for dollars and cents. My code works to piece together the dollars and cents but is it the right way to do it for this instance. Also if there is another easier method of doing my newbie code, feel free to show me where it can be improved. Thanks!

```
<?php

$appid = '8870';

$ht = 'http://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails/?appids=' . $appid;

$fgc = file_get_contents($ht);
$jd = json_decode($fgc, true);

$gdata = $jd[$appid]['data'];

$gname = $gdata['name'];
$gprice = $gdata['price_overview']['final'];
$gdesc = $gdata['detailed_description'];

$gusd = substr($gprice, 0, -2);
$gcent = substr($gprice, 2);

echo $gname. '<br>';
echo 'Price: $' .$gusd. ',' .$gcent;

?>
```

If I may ask another question... can the price data aka $gprice be added to another price data that is fetched, to return a total.

Comment: looks like the price is just stated as a "cents" value, e.g. 5999 = $59.99. try `number_format($price / 100, 2)`.

Comment: $gnprice = number_format($gprice / 100, 2); Worked!

Answer (score 1):

I would essentially do what you are doing except its much simpler to just divide by 100:

Turn the price into a float:

```
$gprice = $gprice / 100;
```

and then use `money_format`

Ref: [PHP Docs - money_format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php)

You could also do this, but there isn't really a need.

```
$gprice = (int) $gdata['price_overview']['final'];
```

Answer (score 0):

The conversion is not bad, but you could also use this:

```
$gusd = $gprice/100;

echo $gname. '<br>';
echo 'Price: $' .str_replace('.', ',', $gusd);
```

or use money_format instead of replace, but it's a little more complicated.

also, to add another you could do it with just the + or += operators like this:

```
$gprice+= $gdata['price_overview']['final'];
```

Comment: The simple math is the solution to my needs and its less code. Thank you for also showing me how to replace the dot with a comma.